# How to get refresh token from Gmail of stored username and password in database

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, refresh-token

I have stored username and passwords in database in want to get all users refresh token programmatically using c# technology.

Is it possible to get refresh token from stored passwords ?

Comment: Does this link help you? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: **DO NOT "store passwords"!**

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called Client login, google shut down client login in 2015.  It is no longer posible to get a refresh token using stored login and passwords.

You should NOT be storing a users Google login and password in your application!  **EVER**

## What you should be doing.

You need to have the user run your application logging into their google account and authorize your application using Oauth2 this will give you an access token and a refresh token you can use in your application.

As you didnt mention which type of application you are working with this is the example for an installed application

```
 var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                             scopes,
                                                                             userName,
                                                                             CancellationToken.None,
                                                                             new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

[Oauth2Authentication.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.cs)